# How can a controller assign two things (X,Y) in a map?

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary

I want to have two pieces of data that can be addressed in the map section.

Take the information from some `TextField`s and put it in `List<double>` so that the `List` can be called somewhere else like down for x,y:

```dart
spots: myValues.asMap().entries. map(([x,y]) {
  return FlSpot(x.value, y.value);
}).toList(),
```

But it gives this error for X

**Error: The parameter 'x' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'MapEntry<int, double>', but the implicit default value is 'null'**

which can receive two data from the user in two separate controls in the TextField :

```dart
late List<double> myValues = [
double.parse(fieldXController.text),double.parse(fieldYController.tex)];
```

I have just started working in this field and I appreciate your help.

Comment: The code you've posted is not valid.  Presumably `entries.Map` and `double.Parse` should instead be `entries.map` and `double.parse`, and `**x**` presumably is your attempt at making `x` appear in bold-faced type, but nobody can tell if you've made any other transcription errors in your question.  **Copy-and-paste code** that demonstrates your problem; do *not* retype it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store in `Map` with `key` as `x`, and `value` as `y`.

Your `myValues` should be as following,

```dart
late Map<double, double> myValues =
<int, double>{double.parse(fieldXController.text), double.parse(fieldYController.text)};
```

and in usage

```dart
spots: myValues.entries.map((entry) {
  return FlSpot(entry.key, entry.value);
}).toList(),
```

if you want to add more entries

```
myValues[double.parse(fieldXController.text)] = double.parse(fieldYController.text);
```